# Datagrid datatrigger not fired when value changes

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, datatrigger

I have a dataGridwith columns that have bindings to some columns in a data table

```
<DataGrid x:Name="WatchersGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding GroupWatchers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding  Path=[Name]}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Path=[Value]}">
                            <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                                </Style>
                            </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="InRange" Binding="{Binding [IsInRange]}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding [IsInRange]}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Crimson"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

i have a data trigger on the "IsInRange" column that sets the foreground property to red if the value is false.
the value inside the data grid column changes but the color property dosent change.
i tried to    NotifyPropertyChanged("[IsInRange]"); when my value is changing but that didnt help
any ideas?

Edit:
My ViewModel

```
public class WatcherControlViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private DataTable _dt;
  private string _groupName;
  public DataRow[] GroupWatchers{get {return _dt.Select("Group = '" + GroupName + "'");}}
  public WatcherControlViewModel(DataTable dt, string name)
    {
        _dt = dt;
        _groupName = name;
       _dt.RowChanged += DataTableChangedEvent;
    }

    private void DataTableChangedEvent(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        NotifyPropertyChanged("GroupWatchers");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("IsInRange");
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Actually, it worked for me.... please show you `ViewModel` class.

Comment: it works for me when i add the value for the first time but if i change the value in the datatable it doesn't update, in my viewmodel i have 'public DataRow[] GroupWatchers{get {return _dt.Select("Group = '" + GroupName + "'");}}' which is the itemsource and i change some of _dt values in the code. after i change i raise ' NotifyPropertyChanged("GroupWatchers");
            NotifyPropertyChanged("[IsInRange]");'

Comment: You don't need `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `GroupWatchers` should be a public `DataTable` property, with `get` and `set`, not `DataRow[]`. Please see how to do it in my post.

Comment: sorry i forget i do a select on the dt in the get, i dont want to show the entire dt just the entires with the same group name

Comment: You only need `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your custom classes. `DataTable` is already "smart" enough for that purpose.

Comment: Your `DataTable` should be filled with only the data you want to show, before binding. Now you're mixing your business logic with your presentation layer. Bad approach.

Comment: why is this a bad approach i have sevral data grid user controls one for every groupname, why should i hold a datatable foreach one? i need all the entries together because i have another object that does calculations for all the groups

Comment: thanks it worked for me with the datatable binding if you have any idea why its not working with the datarow[] binding it will be great!

Comment: I just told you: you're mixing business layer and presentation layer.

Comment: I never tried doing it using `DataRow[]`. Perhaps it is possible to make it work, but i wouldn't even try, just because it is unnecessary, and quite frankly looks just so ugly and plain wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on your `ViewModel` and how you're binding to it. Implying from your XAML, your `ViewModel` should look something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public DataTable WatchersGrid { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        WatchersGrid = new MyDataTable();
    }
}
```

And your binding should look like this:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    private MyViewModel vm;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm = new MyViewModel();
        DataContext = vm;
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        vm.WatchersGrid.Rows[0]["IsInRange"] = !(bool)vm.WatchersGrid.Rows[0]["IsInRange"];
    }
}
```

Note the test button. It switches `IsInRange` value between `true` and `false` for the first row only, for testing purposes.

And the result:

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without square brackets? Does your model implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface?
Could be helpful if you post code behind that view.

Comment: yes my viewmodel implements INotifyPropertyChanged  in the code behind i change the value of the data table with row["IsInRange"] = false; in some data rows.  it didnt help to remove the square brackets @yoger